# pivoting dataframe with two columns of lists

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I have a Dataframe like:

```
matrix = [(222, ['A','B','C'], [1,2,3]),
         (333, ['A','B','D'], [1,3,5])]

df = pd.DataFrame(matrix, columns=['timestamp', 'variable', 'value'])
```

```
timestamp     variable         value   

222           ['A','B','C']    [1,2,3]
333           ['A','B','D']    [1,3,5]
```

and would like to pivot it so that the `timestamp` value is kept, the unique values in the `variable` column become additional columns, and values from `value` are sorted in the respective columns.

The output should look as follows:

```
timestamp   A    B    C    D 

222         1    2    3    nan
333         1    3    nan  5
```

any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [unnest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218931/how-to-unnest-explode-a-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe/53218939#53218939) first , then just `pivot`

```
unnesting(df,['variable','value']).pivot(*df.columns)
Out[79]: 
variable     A    B    C    D
timestamp                    
222        1.0  2.0  3.0  NaN
333        1.0  3.0  NaN  5.0
```

---

```
def unnesting(df, explode):
    idx = df.index.repeat(df[explode[0]].str.len())
    df1 = pd.concat([
        pd.DataFrame({x: np.concatenate(df[x].values)}) for x in explode], axis=1)
    df1.index = idx

    return df1.join(df.drop(explode, 1), how='left')
```

Answer (score 3):

Create dictionary with zip, pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
a = [dict(zip(*x)) for x in zip(df['variable'], df['value'])]
print (a)
[{'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3}, {'A': 1, 'B': 3, 'D': 5}]

df = df[['timestamp']].join(pd.DataFrame(a, index=df.index))
print (df)
   timestamp  A  B    C    D
0        222  1  2  3.0  NaN
1        333  1  3  NaN  5.0
```

If many another columns use [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for extract columns:

```
a = [dict(zip(*x)) for x in zip(df.pop('variable'), df.pop('value'))]

df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(a, index=df.index))
print (df)
   timestamp  A  B    C    D
0        222  1  2  3.0  NaN
1        333  1  3  NaN  5.0
```

Comment: boom - there it is! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the values & column names to a the pd.Series constructor. This will automatically expand the values in your desired shape.

```
df.set_index('timestamp').apply(lambda row: pd.Series(row.value, index=row.variable), axis=1)

# outputs:
             A    B    C    D
timestamp
222        1.0  2.0  3.0  NaN
333        1.0  3.0  NaN  5.0
```